# output information to the template (from the next array)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Stalled, but I can not understand how to display the next array
Have this:

```
return render(request, 'main.html', {'arrImages': arrImages,'title': arrTitle})
```

The `arrImages` array is output without any problems. But how to get the `title`? I do not understand where i have to loop.

```
    <div class="container">
{% for images in arrImages %}
<hr>
    <p class="text-justify"> {{ /////????title }}</p>
    <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ images }}>
{% endfor %}
```

Where i have to put `{% for title in arrTitle %}{% endfor %}` , or is it done in one loop? Sorry for such questions, but in the internet did not find)

I work through the API. Without a database. 
If it's necessary i can attach all the code of `views.py`

Comment: Is `title` a *list* of titles, or just a simple string?

Comment: use context for better coding

Comment: array of strings -   ['A', 'B']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple string

If `title` (which the name suggests), is just a simple string, you do *not* need to loop (since looping over a string means you iterate over the *characters* of that string). You can thus write it as a *variable* somewhere. For example:

```
<div class="container">
{% for images in arrImages %}
<hr>
    <p class="text-justify">{{ title }}</p>
    <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ images }}>
{% endfor %}
```

## List of strings

In case it is a list of strings, and every string corresponds to one image, then you should *`zip`* the two lists together to an iterable of tuples that contain the title and the image source. Although there are extensions to do this in the template, in standard Django, you typically do this with a **`zip(..)`** in the view:

```
return render(request, 'main.html', {'imageTitles': zip(arrImages, arrTitle)})
```

In the template, we then need to *unpack* these 2-tuples:

```
<div class="container">
{% for image, title in imageTitles %}
<hr>
    <p class="text-justify">{{ title }}</p>
    <img class = "col-12 ml-auto col-12 mr-auto" src={{ image}}>
{% endfor %}
```